# Invalid Xpath - not equals to X amount of characters

Tags: xpath

I am trying to get a Xpath match where Variable1 = "Text" and Variable2 not equals 'AB' in the first 2 characters and not equals to 23 characters

What i have currently but it does not seem to be a valid Xpath:

```
/File[Variable1='Text'] and [Variable2[substring(.,1,2) != ‘AB’]] and [Variable2[substring!=(23)]]
```

Please help!

Comment: What should be *"not equals to 23 characters"*? The length of `Variable2` value?

Comment: Also, no body can help you in context of your XML if you didn't post the XML

Comment: Yes the length of variable 2. I am looking more for the grammar that means not equal exact number of characters

Comment: You already got that: `!=`. You should be looking for function that get length of the var value: `string-length()`. Anyways, some other problem need to be fixed in your XPath. Please post relevant portion of your XML

Comment: The first part of the Xpath syntax works, only the substring length doesnt.                             /book[Variable1='text'][Variable2[substring(.,1.2) != 'AB'][Variable2[substring-length(24)]]

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, you can use [`string-length()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/string-length) to get number of characters in the variable :

```
/book[Variable1='text']
     [Variable2[substring(.,1.2)!='AB' and string-length()!=24]]
```

Alternatively, you can use `not(starts-with())` to replace `substring()!='xxx'` :

```
/book[Variable1='text']
     [Variable2[not(starts-with(.,'AB')) and string-length()!=24]]
```